# Upon running the i get a pop up windows screen saying "prg.exe has stopped working."

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char str[100];
  cout << "Enter a string : ";
  gets(str);
  cout << "The words containing y in their last place are : ";
  cout << "\n";
  for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    int j = i + 1;
    if((str[i] == 'y') && (str[j] == ' '))
    {
      int k;
      cout << 134;
      char stress[50];
      int m = 0;
      k = i;
      for(; (str[k] != ' ') || (k != 0); k--, m++)
      {
        stress[m] = str[k];
      }
      stress[m] = '\0';
      int g;
      for(g = 0; stress[g] != '\0'; g++)
        ;
      char strain[g];
      for(int n = 0, q = k - 1; q >= 0; n++, q--)
      {
        strain[n] = stress[q];
      }
      strain[g] = '\0';
      for(int p = 0; p < g; p++)
      {
        cout << strain[p];
      }

      cout << "\n";
      cout << 1;
    }
    cout << 12;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This c++ program is to display the word containing 'y' as its last letter. I used cout<<12 cout<<1 etc.. to know which part of program is working.
Dont get confused by seeing strain and stress. They are just strings.
I am using codeblocks in windows 7

Upon running the program i get a pop up windows screen saying "prg.exe has stopped working."
Please someone tell me why this error is occuring.
I use codeblocks
I will be really grateful.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code watching values of variables.  Debugging is often faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect your code or debug your program for you.

Comment: @tobi303 Don't be too hard on them, beginners don't generally know good formatting rules (or how to use tools to make them easier to use).

Comment: Why do you need to loop?  The last letter is at `stress[stress.length() - 1]`.  Compare this with `'y'`.

Comment: _"Upon running the program i get a pop up"_ What, immediately? Or once a specific part of the program runs?

Comment: @Cubic I didnt consider the comment to be too harsh... anyhow it is obolete

Comment: The error occurs because your program index outside the arrays `str` and `stress`. The best way to handle this is to use a debugger and step through the program to find out how things go wrong and then revise the code to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Thanks. I found out what was wrong int the program using debugger. It indicated there was a segmentation error in the code    stress[m] = str[k];

Comment: But once I changed      for(; (str[k] != ' ') || (k != 0); k--, m++)             to        for(;str[k]!=' ';k--,m++)     it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might have errors because of using `gets()` function, because when you are using  `gets()` you need to know the amount of characters you will get. It was officialy removed by 2011 standart, but almost every C implementation uses it. So to avoid that dangerous function you can use:

- `getline()`, which is very easy to use - like that:

  `getline(cin,str);`
- `fgets()`, it is used like `gets`, but you need to mention how many characters you will read:

  `fgets(str, num_of_chars, cin);`

Comment: This appears to be more of a comment than an actual to answer to the question (I realise you don't have commenting privileges yet).

Comment: I understand that you want to get your rating up but posting incomplete answers(or comment as an answer) is not the way to go. With slightly more effort you could have verified your suggestion and made i a real answer.